# PseudoCode for Python: finding an item in a list

Tags: python, pseudocode, python-idle

I'm working on pseudocode for a program that will allow a single listitem to be found in a listofitems. Pseudocode is still a bit of a foreign concept to me, and I could be going about this 110% wrong... so this is the pseudocode...

```
listofitems= [1, 2, 'a']

define function findItem(object1, object2, object3):
    listItem = raw_input("Find this item in the list: ")
    for each item in findItem:
        if listItem = object1 in findItem or listItem = object2 in findItem or listItem = object3 in findItem:
            print True
        else:
            print False

findItem(listofitems):
```

how left from right am I???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

17 years ago I called Python 'executable pseudocode' because it at least partly replaces the need for unexecutable and therefore untestable pseudocode.  Better, in a case like yours, to write test data (as you did), test code (which you did not), and real code that can be tested. While I recommend beginning with Python 3 if possible, I started the below with 3 lines to make it run the same on Python 2.

```
import sys
if sys.version_info.major < 3:
    input = rawinput

mylist = ['1', '2', 'a']
myset = {'3.14', 'b'}

def find(target, iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        if item == target:
            return True
    return False

assert find('2', mylist) is True
assert find('2', myset) is False

# print(find(input("Item to find")))
```